# Enabling: Raster and Topology

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, mapserver, topology

I'm new to GIS and tile servers. I've installed TinyOWS pretty successfully except for what looks like to be some dependency issues. I have installed PostGIS and also PostgreSQL. PostGIS is supposed to come with raster and topology support, so I assume it is already installed but not enabled. Anyway I can't find any good online resources for this so I need some help.

Here is my error:

```
NOTICE:  Function postgis_gdal_version() not found.  Is raster support enabled     and rtpostgis.sql installed?
NOTICE:  Function postgis_topology_scripts_installed() not found. Is topology support enabled and topology.sql installed?
NOTICE:  Function postgis_raster_scripts_installed() not found. Is raster support enabled and rtpostgis.sql installed?
NOTICE:  Function postgis_raster_lib_version() not found. Is raster support enabled and rtpostgis.sql installed?
```

Update: 
I've tried creating an extension to these like as follows:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Then I get the following:

```
ERROR: PostGIS is already installed in schema 'public', uninstall first
```

Comment: What version of PostGIS and PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: The version is 2.1. Sorry, probably should've included that.

Comment: PostgreSQL is version 9.3

Answer (score 2):

The topology extension has to be `CREATE`d separately:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
```

As to why also your raster functions fail: could you verify you are trying to use a version of PostGIS with raster support compiled in? (see http://www.postgis.net/docs/RT_FAQ.html#idp61635392)